# EditText/TextView to ListView

Tags: android

I have two activities. FirstActivity contains an onClick button which takes to SecondActivity. SecondActivity contains multiple EditText and a Save Button. After clicking save button I want to show all the data in the FirstActivity in ListView. I did it using TextView in FirstActivity but I am not able to use to ListAdapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ListView list_view;
    List list;
    private Button FloatingActionButton;

    private TextView vortext;
    private TextView nachtext;
    private TextView strtext;
    private TextView orttext;
    private TextView text1;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayAdapter;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        vortext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vortext);
        nachtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nachtext);
        strtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strtext);
        orttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orttext);
        list = new ArrayList<String>();






        vortext.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Vorname"));
        nachtext.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Nachname"));
        strtext.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Strasse"));
        orttext.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Ort"));



        list_view =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);


        String [] strings = new String[] {};
        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>> listItem = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>();
       HashMap<String,String>map;

       map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       map.put();
       listItem.add(map);


        ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listitem,strings);

        FloatingActionButton myFab =  findViewById(R.id.fab);
        myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class), 12);

            }




        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 12) {
            String vs = data.getExtras().getString("vs");
            Log.d("MainActivity",vs);

            String ns = data.getExtras().getString("ns");
            Log.d("MainActivity",ns);

            String ss = data.getExtras().getString("ss");
            Log.d("MainActivity",ss);

    String os = data.getExtras().getString("os");
            Log.d("MainActivity",os);
        }


    }
}
```

Here this is my DetailsActivity

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private  EditText Vorname;
    private  EditText Nachname;
    private  EditText Strasse;
    private  EditText Ort;
    private  Button Save;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        Vorname  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Vorname);
        Nachname  =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Nachname);
        Strasse  =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Strasse);
        Ort  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ort);
        Save    =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);

        Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String vs = Vorname.getText().toString();
                String ns = Nachname.getText().toString();
                String ss = Strasse.getText().toString();
                String os = Ort.getText().toString();






                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("vs", vs);
                intent.putExtra("ns",ns);
                intent.putExtra("ss",ss);
                intent.putExtra("os",os);


                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Will you try with SharedPreference !!

Comment: Where is your code to set Adapter with ListView like ListView.setAdapter();

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: What are you trying to do I cannot understand, First make global list, then make adapter, now on activity result add the data to the list and call adapter.notifydatasetchange() you will see the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run this sample, it may helps you

FirstActivity

```
   public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private List<String> mCityList;
   LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
   RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
  SampleDataAdapter adapter;
  Button button;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_activity);
 mCityList=new ArrayList<String>();
 mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
 button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonFirst);
 mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
 adapter = new SampleDataAdapter(mCityList,this);
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
     }
 });

}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> returnValue = data.getStringArrayListExtra("LIST");
            mCityList.addAll(returnValue);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
 }
  }
```

list_activity.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonFirst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
```

SecondActivity

```
  public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  Button button;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
 button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSecond);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
         list.add("A");
         list.add("B");
         list.add("C");
         list.add("D");
         list.add("E");
         list.add("E");
         list.add("G");

         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.putStringArrayListExtra("LIST",list);
         setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
         finish();
     }
 });
 }
 }
```

second_Activity.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSecond"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Second"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

SampleDataADapter

```
  public class SampleDataAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleDataAdapter.Items> {
private List<String> list;
private Context context;
public SampleDataAdapter(List<String> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public SampleDataAdapter.Items onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_text, parent, false);
    return new Items(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SampleDataAdapter.Items holder, int position) {
    holder.mEventName.setText(list.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class Items extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mEventName;
    public Items(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mEventName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
}
```

item_text.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
tools:context="com.example.android.broadcasereceiver.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

if you want to this with ListView just add in OnActivityResult

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> returnValue = data.getStringArrayListExtra("LIST");
            ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, returnValue);
            mListView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

        }
enter code here
```

and remove SampleDataAdapter related code from FirstActivity and take ListView instead of RecyclerView

Comment: Thanks @Avinash. That was a great help. Would it be possible for you to also explain the case in which I do not have predefined string such as "A", "B".. in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I found so many issues in your code. for ex- you didn't set adapter to your list, you were using two different list. So I modified your code. Please use this code. You need to take list as **Global Variable**, and you need to set adapter to your list view. And when you are taking your results back from second activity then add those elements in your list and call `ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
to get new data in your listview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView list_view;
List list;
private Button FloatingActionButton;

private TextView vortext;
private TextView nachtext;
private TextView strtext;
private TextView orttext;
private TextView text1;

private android.widget.ArrayAdapter<String> ArrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> strings;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    vortext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vortext);
    nachtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nachtext);
    strtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strtext);
    orttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orttext);
    list = new ArrayList<String>();


    vortext.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Vorname"));
    nachtext.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Nachname"));
    strtext.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Strasse"));
    orttext.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Ort"));


    list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);


    strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, strings);
    list_view.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter);

    com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton myFab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class), 12);

        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 12) {
        String vs = data.getExtras().getString("vs");
        Log.d("MainActivity", vs);
        strings.add(vs);
        String ns = data.getExtras().getString("ns");
        Log.d("MainActivity", ns);
        strings.add(ns);

        String ss = data.getExtras().getString("ss");
        Log.d("MainActivity", ss);
        strings.add(ss);

        String os = data.getExtras().getString("os");
        Log.d("MainActivity", os);
        strings.add(os);
        ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}
```

}